# PowerBI calculate between two dates with USERELATIONSHIP

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 3 different kinds of date which are connected to main date-table. I need to calculate with use of USERELATIONSHIP data between two dates. It works somehow, but it shows me wrong numbers. Instead of 23 in July it shows me 17. And May is completely empty,
although it has 2 tickets.

```
TabelleFilter_AltTest = 

var test = MAX(MonthTable[Last-Month-Year])

var exc =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(tt_infopointtickets[tt_closingdate]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('tt_infopointtickets'[tt_closingdate], 'tt_date(x-axis)'[tt_date]),
    FILTER(tt_infopointtickets,
        tt_infopointtickets[tt_closingdate] >= MIN(MonthTable[First-Month-Year]) && 
        tt_infopointtickets[tt_closingdate] <= MAX(MonthTable[Last-Month-Year])
    )
)

return exc
```

I could make like 3 different date-tables and connect them, but it wouldn't work, because I have a chart, where all these dates are counted and compared.

[image: Model]

Comment: Hello, How did you create your main date table ? There should be no gap in your date table no matter what, and mark your main date table "mark as date table".

Comment: There are no gaps, and the table is marked as date table.

Comment: Good to know it. Can you please share your model view? You can put it into your post as a screenshot so that lots of people can react faster to your problem.

Comment: It seems that you have a 3rd table(month table) which doesn't appear on your model view.

Comment: There are other tables with other stuff. But all marked dates are connected with _date.